# Is there any way to reveal the entire minimap?

Tags: civilization-5

If I remember correctly, Civilization 4 offered some technology that revealed the entire minimap. It didn't break fog of war, but at least it allowed you to see where all the cities were and what the terrain was like.

So far in Civilization 5, I haven't seen any equivalent to that. I just decided to have a go on the largest size map, and exploring has been daunting, to say the least. Is there any technology I can keep in mind that will fill in any gaps that are left from my exploration efforts?

Comment: buy it (world map) from the other players

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Satellites technology reveals unexplored tiles.  This shows city locations, terrain types, natural wonders (all remaining wonders are discovered when satellites is researched).

Even with satellites, normal line of sight rules apply to view unit locations.

---

If researching satellites does not reveal the map for you, you aren't playing the latest version and need to update your game.

Comment: I´d like to mention, that researching satellites doesn´t automatically let you meet the remaining civs and city-states, you still have to establish contact by actually being able to see them, not just having the tile revealed.